# `Server not found in Kerberos database` for DNS

Tags: java, dns, ldap, kerberos

I have DNS over four ad-servers. When I'm trying to connect to DNS to validate Kerberos ticket I see this error: `Server not found in Kerberos database`. But when I connect to single ad-server directly I don't have any errors. Does anyone know what the reason might be? And how to connect to DNS without this errors? Thank you a lot!

P.S. Algorithm for DNS is round-robin

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are probably missing the SRV Records required by Microsoft Active Directory for locating services. Take a look at: 

https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Verify%20DNS%20Records